# Combination of for-loop and ifelse in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to decide between "Yes" and "No" in R, if a specific (and variable) value is exceeded.
For each value tested a new column with the different decisions should be created.

Here is a manually created example:

```
Test.data <- data.frame(c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100))
colnames(Test.data) <- c("Test")

Test.data$Test1 <- ifelse(Test.data$Test > 10, "Yes", "No")
Test.data$Test2 <- ifelse(Test.data$Test > 20, "Yes", "No")
Test.data$Test3 <- ifelse(Test.data$Test > 30, "Yes", "No")

Test.data
```

This simple example gives the following output:

```
   Test Test1 Test2 Test3
1    10    No    No    No
2    20   Yes    No    No
3    30   Yes   Yes    No
4    40   Yes   Yes   Yes
5    50   Yes   Yes   Yes
6    60   Yes   Yes   Yes
7    70   Yes   Yes   Yes
8    80   Yes   Yes   Yes
9    90   Yes   Yes   Yes
10  100   Yes   Yes   Yes
```

Is there a way to do this with a for-loop? I already tried different stuff like the following code, but it seems to be nonsense, since it doesn't create new columns and so on:

```
n = c(seq(from=10, to=100, by=10))

for(i in n) {
ifelse(Test.data$Test > i, "Yes", "No")
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do the assignment  (`<-`) of the output from `ifelse` to a string created with `paste` for the column names.  Also, instead of looping over `n`, we do the loop over the sequence of 'n'

```
for(i in seq_along(n)) {
        Test.data[paste0("Test", i)] <- ifelse(Test.data$Test > n[i], "Yes", "No")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try something like below

```
cbind(Test.data, ifelse(sapply(c(10, 20, 30), `<`, Test.data$Test), "Yes", "No"))
```

which gives

```
   Test   1   2   3
1    10  No  No  No
2    20 Yes  No  No
3    30 Yes Yes  No
4    40 Yes Yes Yes
5    50 Yes Yes Yes
6    60 Yes Yes Yes
7    70 Yes Yes Yes
8    80 Yes Yes Yes
9    90 Yes Yes Yes
10  100 Yes Yes Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `purrr::map_dfc` :

```
vals <- c(10, 20, 30)

result <- cbind(Test.data, purrr::map_dfc(vals, 
                 ~ifelse(Test.data$Test > .x, 'Yes', 'No')))
names(result)[-1] <- paste0('Test', seq_along(vals))
result

#   Test Test1 Test2 Test3
#1    10    No    No    No
#2    20   Yes    No    No
#3    30   Yes   Yes    No
#4    40   Yes   Yes   Yes
#5    50   Yes   Yes   Yes
#6    60   Yes   Yes   Yes
#7    70   Yes   Yes   Yes
#8    80   Yes   Yes   Yes
#9    90   Yes   Yes   Yes
#10  100   Yes   Yes   Yes
```